# Code does not terminate on second iteration in Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

On second iteration the task appears to hang at line :

```
val wordCountWithLabelsCollect = wordCountWithLabels.collect
```

This is the Scala output :

```
5/06/19 15:49:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting Stage 1 (MappedValuesRDD[3] at mapValues at Ques.scala:33), which has no missing parents
15/06/19 15:49:33 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(2480) called with curMem=2219, maxMem=1030823608
15/06/19 15:49:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1 stored as values in memory (estimated size 2.4 KB, free 983.1 MB)
15/06/19 15:49:33 INFO MemoryStore: ensureFreeSpace(1812) called with curMem=4699, maxMem=1030823608
15/06/19 15:49:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_1_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 1812.0 B, free 983.1 MB)
15/06/19 15:49:33 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_1_piece0 in memory on localhost:54590 (size: 1812.0 B, free: 983.1 MB)
15/06/19 15:49:33 INFO BlockManagerMaster: Updated info of block broadcast_1_piece0
15/06/19 15:49:33 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 1 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:838
15/06/19 15:49:33 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 1 missing tasks from Stage 1 (MappedValuesRDD[3] at mapValues at Ques.scala:33)
15/06/19 15:49:33 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 1.0 with 1 tasks
```

Scala code :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

object Ques extends App {

  val data = getUncategorisedData

  data.foreach(document => {

    runner

  })

  case class Document(label: String, text: String)

  def reduceList(list: List[(String, Int)]) = list.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.aggregate(0)(_ + _._2, _ + _))

  def runner = {
    val trainingData = getSC.parallelize(

      List(
        Document("sport", "this is text for document spor a"),
        Document("sport", "this spor is text for document spor b"),
        Document("news", "this is such a new categorise data")))

    val counts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, Int)])] = trainingData.map(doc => ((doc.label, doc.text.split(" ").toList.map(w => (w, 1)))))

    val mergedList = counts.mapValues((list: List[(String, Int)]) => reduceList(list).toList)
    val wordCountWithLabels: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, List[(String, Int)])] = mergedList.reduceByKey((accum: List[(String, Int)], value: List[(String, Int)]) =>
      {
        val valueMap = value.toMap
        val accumMap = accum.toMap
        val mergedMap = accumMap ++ valueMap.map { case (k, v) => k -> (v + accumMap.getOrElse(k, 0)) }
        mergedMap.toList
      })

    val wordCountWithLabelsCollect = wordCountWithLabels.collect
    wordCountWithLabels.collect
  }

  def getUncategorisedData: RDD[Document] = {
    lazy val trainingData = getSC.parallelize(

      List(
        Document("", "this is text for document a"),
        Document("", "this is text for document b"),
        Document("", "this is text for for document c")))

    trainingData

  }

  lazy val getSC = {

    val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")
      .setAppName("process")
      .setSparkHome("C:\\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4\\spddark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4\\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "3g")
      .set("deploy-mode", "standalone")
      .set("SPARK_CONF_DIR", "c:\\data\\sparkConfig")

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    sc
  }
}
```

What could be the issue here ?

Invoke collect multiple times on same collection should not be an issue ?

If I invoke runner in succession :

```
runner
runner
```

Then it terminates.

Update :

Simpler example of same behavior :

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
import org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions

object Ques extends App {

  val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local")
    .setAppName("process")
    .setSparkHome("C:\\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4\\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4\\spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "3g")

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val data = sc.parallelize(List(""))

  val counts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String)] = sc.parallelize(List(("")))

  data.foreach(document => {
    counts.collect
  })

}
```

This code also never terminates. It appears cannot invoke collect more than once within `foreach` function ?

Update 2 :

I'm not sure why but returning everything to the driver prior to running a transformation will cause termination :

```
data.collect.foreach(document => {
    counts.collect
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the short answer here is that you are trying to invoke an action from inside a transformation.  Actions return a value to the driver; invoking an action from inside a transformation doesn't make sense because transformations are executed by workers, not by the driver.  I can't find any place where the documentation is more explicit than [this section of the programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#rdd-operations).